# What kind of JOINs does CockroachDB support?

Tags: cockroachdb

I saw that CockroachDB offers `JOIN` support in [this blog post](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/blog/better-sql-joins-in-cockroachdb/), but it doesn't mention what level of `JOIN`s are supported. Are all of the major types of joins supported, or are there limitations?

Answer (score 1):

CockroachDB supports the major `JOIN` types:

- `INNER`
- `FULL OUTER`
- `LEFT`
- `RIGHT`

If you need it, you can find the CockroachDB `JOIN` documentation [here](https://www.cockroachlabs.com/docs/table-expressions.html#join-expressions).